# How to call different var strings for jquery tooltip inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, tooltip

I would like to create multiple strings within this same function and make this code more useable across website.

My JS code look like this:

```
    function() {$(".tool-tip-wrapper").click(function () {
      $(".tool-tip",this).html("<img src='/images/ui-elements-sprite.png' class='top-arrow'><p>This is string one.</p><div class='close'></div>").toggle('fast');
    });
```

My html code look like this:

```
<div class="tool-tip-wrapper"> click me
    <div class="tool-tip"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the variable parts of it?

Comment: What does the mean of "multiple strings within this same function" ?

Comment: after .html I would like to add strings like tooltipone ("I am tooltip one")
tooltiptwo ("I am tooltip two")
tooltipthree ("I am tooltip three")

Comment: or can how can I create different functions for different strings and call the from html? Sorry for the confusion, I am newbie!

Comment: I think I am very close but having syntax error. I created 2 functions inside parent function. and each function has its own string and using on click function:
`function() {
$(".tool-tip-wrapper").click(
 function bestBet () {
  $(".tool-tip",this).html("I am string one").toggle('fast');
 };
 
 function shobi () {
  $(".tool-tip",this).html("I am string two").toggle('fast');
 };

};`

Answer (score 0):

Below markup will solve the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tool-tip-wrapper").click(function(){
                                                $(".tool-tip",this).html("<p>"+this.title+"</p><div class='close'></div>").toggle('fast');
                                           });
});
</script>   
</head>

<body>
<div class="tool-tip-wrapper" title="This is string one.">
    click me
    <div class="tool-tip"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```